# Chrome Extension suddenly not working, Errors page is blank

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm new to Chrome Extensions and am trying to make a simple 'Hello World' extension - all it does is inject a .css file that makes 'h1' tags red.

This worked fine, until today when I resumed working on it and couldn't get it to work again.

I noticed there is an Errors button against the Extension `chrome://extensions/`, but clicking it reveals nothing - a blank page. I removed and re-installed the extension, but the issue remains.

I am not getting any other errors and am stumped as to why this suddenly stopped working.

Would anyone know if I've done anything wrong?

My Manifest (V3) file:

```
{
    "name": "Hello World",
    "description": "Test",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "icons": {
        "16": "/images/icon-16x16.png",
        "32": "/images/icon-32x32.png",
        "48": "/images/icon-48x48.png",
        "128": "/images/icon-128x128.png"
    },
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
    "action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_icon": {
            "16": "/images/icon-16x16.png",
            "32": "/images/icon-32x32.png",
            "48": "/images/icon-48x48.png",
            "128": "/images/icon-128x128.png"
        }
    },
    "options_page": "options.html",
    "permissions": [
        "storage",
        "activeTab",
        "scripting",
        "tabs"
    ]
}
```

My background.js file:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, changeInfo, tab) => {
    if (changeInfo.status === 'complete' && /^http/(tab.url)) {
        chrome.scripting.insertCSS({
            target: { tabId: tabId },
            files: ["./styles.css"]
        })
            .then(() => {
                console.log("INJECTED THE FOREGROUND STYLES.");
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
});
```

styles.css simply contains:

```
h1 {
    color: red !important;
}
```

My popup.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello World</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div><p>Hello World</p></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And my options.html exists but is empty.

Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: `/^http/(tab.url)` is an error. I think you want `/^http/.test(tab.url)`

Comment: @Pointy thanks - that's worked. Want to make that an answer? Also do you know what that means exactly?

Comment: Note that the popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu. You'll see the error there.

Comment: That's a regular expression (`/^http/`), and *probably* what it's trying to do is make sure the tab doesn't contain an "about:" page or something like that. The `.test()` method returns true/false based on whether the string matches the pattern.

Comment: @MeltingDog Learn what [Regular expressions](https://javascript.info/regular-expressions) are and how to use them. In the meantime, you can use `tab.url.startsWith("http")`, which does the same thing as your regular expression. See https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_startswith.asp

Answer (score 2):

An error is output to DevTools of the service worker.

> Error in event handler: TypeError: /^http/ is not a function
> at

Here is where the error occurs.

```js
    if (changeInfo.status === 'complete' && /^http/(tab.url)) {
```